# Yii2 framework controller throwing error - Getting unknown property

Tags: php, yii2

I am looking into some legacy code. Php application is throwing an error when I want to edit a page element. Not even sure why it means. **Documenttemplateelement** has no `repeat` attribute.

Error:

```
Exception (Unknown Property) 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: common\models\Documenttemplateelement::repeat' 

in C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:154

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\BaseActiveRecord.php(298): yii\base\Component->__get('repeat')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php(2233): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->__get('repeat')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php(1826): yii\helpers\BaseHtml::getAttributeValue(Object(common\models\Documenttemplateelement), 'repeat')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseHtml.php(1664): yii\helpers\BaseHtml::activeListInput('dropDownList', Object(common\models\Documenttemplateelement), 'repeat', Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(654): yii\helpers\BaseHtml::activeDropDownList(Object(common\models\Documenttemplateelement), 'repeat', Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yii-ui\yii2-materialize\ActiveField.php(189): yii\widgets\ActiveField->dropDownList(Array, Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\backend\views\documentmanager\element.php(50): yiiui\yii2materialize\ActiveField->dropDownList(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(348): require('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(257): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array, Object(backend\controllers\DocumentmanagerController))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(386): yii\base\View->render('element', Array, Object(backend\controllers\DocumentmanagerController))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\backend\controllers\DocumentmanagerController.php(228): yii\base\Controller->render('element', Array)
#12 [internal function]: backend\controllers\DocumentmanagerController->actionElementUpdate('137')
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('element-update', Array)
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('documentmanager...', Array)
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\ddtool\backend\web\index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Looks to me like the problem starts at #6 (= in the view). You are trying to access the attribute `repeat` in the model `common\models\Documenttemplateelement`. The error message clearly states that it doesnt have that attribute. But without any code there is not much we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know it was coming from the view. There were so many files referenced in debug log and it was confusing where to look.